# How to store data from ng-repeat into a variable to send it to API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to the save selected value from ng-repeat in UI (user select it from drop down)and save it to a variable.

```
 function saveToDb() {  
                        console.log('in func')
                        var postToApi = [];     
                        vm.newStudent.ethnic = [];
                        angular.forEach(vm.newStudent.ethnicity, function (value, data) {
                            vm.newStudent.ethnic.push({
                                ethnicity: value.ethnicity
                            });
                        });
         var regNewStudent = { 
        ethnic: vm.newStudent.ethnic,
             }
                    postToApi.push(regNewStudent)
                    console.log('Student Saved')
```

Comment: where is the HTML for the ng-repeat is it inside a select tag, please provide more details

Comment: actually if is in a dropdown, you must asigned a ng-model so thats the variable stored in the $scope, so you can send it trought your api.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco  
Need a suggestion for the same example Object structure should be defined: - If the data is undefined in an object do not send that object to api - if the property should contain an array of object, array of string or array of numbers

Comment: @JesusCarrasco While storing multiple values in a variable, if a value is undefined, how will we add conditions to it so it wont store in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your select is multiple so when you select an item in the dropdown, will be an array of object.

This example show with your data how to save in the var `regNewStudent` an object `ethnic` is an array.
Here is a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/Tf2uGk8uJADkgOzdG7I8/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

    <select ng-model="vm.newStudent.ethnicity" placeholder="Ethnicity" aria-label="Ethnicity" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.code'}" multiple ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in vm.listofEthnicity">
    </select>

{{vm.newStudent.ethnicity}}

<button ng-click="vm.save()">Save</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  var regNewStudent = { 
          ethnic: ''
      };

  vm.listofEthnicity = [ 
    { "code": 111, "name": "New Zealand European/Pākehā" }, 
    { "code": 121, "name": "British / Irish" }, 
    { "code": 122, "name": "Dutch" }, 
    { "code": 123, "name": "Greek" }
    ];

    vm.save = function() {
      regNewStudent = { 
          ethnic: vm.newStudent.ethnicity,
      };
        // cause i dont have the postToApi to factory i just console it.
        console.log(regNewStudent);
        //postToApi.push(regNewStudent); //uncomment on your code.
    };

});
```

Comment: thanks but i just want to save this in variable (regNewStudent)

Comment: this is an example you can adapt to your logic and local variables, you can change the vm.selectedEtnia to vm.regNewStudent

Comment: any suggestion to existing one that i posted??

Comment: if you provide the ng-repeat html, and the controller i could help to adapt it

Comment: check update answer

Comment: Ethnic still undefined

Comment: share your json, to put the same. and i make a plknr

Comment: {
  "ethnicity": [
    {
      "code": 111,
      "name": "New Zealand European/Pākehā"
    },
    {
      "code": 121,
      "name": "British / Irish"
    },
    {
      "code": 122,
      "name": "Dutch"
    },
    {
      "code": 123,
      "name": "Greek"
    }]}

Comment: i put an plnkr with an example with your data. you provide hope helps. also update the answer, telling you  that the `ethnic` is an array cause your select is a multiple

Comment: Awesome thanks Jesus.. Many more to come :)

Comment: Need a suggestion for the same example Object structure should be defined:
- If the data is undefined in an object do not send that object to api 
- if the property should contain an array of object, array of string or array of numbers

Comment: check same plknr is update with a condition when is array

Comment: While storing multiple values in a variable, if a value is undefined, how will we add conditions to it so it wont store in the variable?